# using var makes the script not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for a math game:

HTML:

```
<div id="problem"></div>
<input id="answer" type="text">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="answerMessage"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#answer').focus();
    $('#problem').append( newProblem() );


    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        var userAnswer = $('#answer').val();

        if ( checkAnswer(number1, number2, userAnswer) ) {
            $('#answerMessage').html('');
            $('#answerMessage').append("Great!");

            $('#problem').html('');
            $('#problem').append( newProblem() );

            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#answer').focus();
        } else {
            $('#answerMessage').html('');
            $('#answerMessage').append("Oops");

            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#answer').focus();
        }
    });

});

function checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer) {
    if ( number1 + number2 == answer ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function newProblem() { // could just return 1 number, then we call it twice.
    var number1 = Math.floor(99 * Math.random()) + 1; // adding var here fails
    var number2 = Math.floor(99 * Math.random()) + 1;
    return number1 + " + " + number2; 
}
```

When I add `var` in front of number1 and number2, in the `newProblem()` function, the script fails to work. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: number1 is not defined`.

Why is so?

Comment: best way change the `names` of the `variables` and `arguments`..seems some problem with the `scoping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly organize your application before even *touching* jQuery:

```
function AddingGame() {
    this.number1 = null;
    this.number2 = null;

    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
    }

    this.newProblem = function() {
        this.number1 = randomNumber(1, 100);
        this.number2 = randomNumber(1, 100);
    };

    this.checkAnswer = function(answer) {
        return this.number1 + this.number2 == answer;
    };

    this.problemText = function() {
        return this.number1 + ' + ' + this.number2;
    }

    this.newProblem();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var game = new AddingGame();

    $('#problem').text(game.problemText());
    $('#answer').focus();

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var answer = $('#answer').val();
        $('#answer').val('').focus();

        if (game.checkAnswer(answer)) {
            $('#answerMessage').text("Great!");

            game.newProblem();
            $('#problem').text(game.problemText());
        } else {
            $('#answerMessage').append("Oops");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, very helpful I like this organization, learned from your post.

Answer (score 3):

because `number1` and `number2` are local to the `newProblem()` function scope so it is not available in the click handler. The solution is to declare it in a scope shared between both the methods

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#answer').focus();
    $('#problem').append(newProblem());


    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var userAnswer = $('#answer').val();

        if (checkAnswer(number1, number2, userAnswer)) {
            $('#answerMessage').html('');
            $('#answerMessage').append("Great!");

            $('#problem').html('');
            $('#problem').append(newProblem());

            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#answer').focus();
        } else {
            $('#answerMessage').html('');
            $('#answerMessage').append("Oops");

            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#answer').focus();
        }
    });

    function checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer) {
        if (number1 + number2 == answer) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //make these two to be in a closure scope accessible to both newProblem and click handler
    var number1, number2;

    function newProblem() { // could just return 1 number, then we call it twice.
        number1 = Math.floor(99 * Math.random()) + 1; // adding var here fails
        number2 = Math.floor(99 * Math.random()) + 1;
        return number1 + " + " + number2;
    }
});
```

I will declare the variables inside the dom ready handler and move the methods `newProblem` and `checkAnswer` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

try to declare the variables on top of the script

```
var number1,number2;
$(document).ready(function() {
```

you are using them globally

Comment: Thanks -- so basically to make the script work, I was never declaring the variables. I guess it's good practice to declare them anyway (in global scope)?

Comment: @DanyP Not quite. If you don't use `var`, then the variable becomes an implicit global variable declaration (on the `window` object), and makes it available *everywhere*. This is generally very bad practice, as keeping track of globals that can be used, and more dangerously changed, anywhere is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

number1 and number2 are defined as a local variables for **function newProblem()**. define them globally(within script, outside of all functions).

Answer (score -1):

It's declared inside a function, which means it can only be accessed there. If you want a variable accessible globally, you can remove the var. 
In your code you are using the same variables here:

```
 if ( checkAnswer(number1, number2, userAnswer) ) {
}
```

Comment: check your code you are using number1 and number2 in checkanswer function call, that means that variables are global not local variable. Check my edited answer.